# Android Studio - Rendering Problems, Attribute Text Size is not valid

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-styles

I am trying to add dynamic font change settings through application. I have used typical style and attr method but I am getting this warning.

> Rendering Problems "?attr/font_medium" in attribute "textSize" is not a valid format. (16 similar errors not shown)

Example TextView

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/labelWeeks"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                    android:paddingRight="2dp"
                    style="@style/TextViewStyle"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_white"/>
```

My style.xml has this

```
 <style name="TextViewStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:text">@string/app_name</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">?attr/font_small</item>
</style>
```

and attr.xml has this

```
<declare-styleable name="FontStyle">
    <attr name="font_small" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="font_medium" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="font_large" format="dimension" />
</declare-styleable>
```

So, What is this warning is all about and how to reslove it

Answer (score 0):

this tutorial will help you out.

Tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 0):

Your attr.xml file has nothing to do with ?attr/some_attribute references.
`<declare-styleable>` tags are for defining custom view attributes, such as View has "layout_width" and "layout_height" etc. ([learn more about declare-styleable](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr))

To define custom dimensions use res/values/dimens.xml file, and define your values as such:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="font_small">12sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="font_medium">14sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="font_large">16sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And then reference them:

```
<style name="TextViewStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:text">@string/app_name</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_small</item>
</style>
```